# Spring Social Twitter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, twitter, spring-social-twitter

I am new to `Spring` and trying to make a web application that reads the last 20 tweets of an user with `getUserTimeline(screenName);`. So far I made this Tutorial from Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-twitter/ and changed the request so I can see the last 20 tweets of the user. But before I can see them I'm getting redirected to the Twitter authorization site. I saw a lot about `Connection` in the reference but I'm not shure which is the best one for my app. I want to save the tweets in a `Database` and fetch them to the view.

Comment: Have you registered your application in twitter?? You can take help from https://spring.io/guides/gs/register-twitter-app/

Comment: Yes I did. Otherwise I couldn't even get this tweets as i described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.. It needs an Twitter Template with all tokens in the application.properties file.

Comment: I know this is very very late, but would it still be possible for you to share your code ? I am struggling with the same problem. many thanks !